# Замена символа во время ввода datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Есть необходимость заменять символ во время ввода текста в ячейку datagridview, нужно "," менять на ":". Посоветуйте как реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            var txtBox = e.Control as TextBox;            
            if (e.Control is TextBox && txtBox != null)
            {
                txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(ItemTxtBox_TextChanged);
            }
        }

        void ItemTxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var txt = sender as TextBox;
                if (txt.Text != null && txt.Text.Trim() != "")
                {
                    txt.Text = txt.Text.Replace(",", ":");
                    txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length;
                    txt.SelectionLength = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
```

Рабочий пример кода с передвижением курсора получил [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/d80d73a7-c829-453a-a1a2-02b94f5dbd2d/-datagridview?forum=fordesktopru) .

Answer (score 1):

Подпишите датагрид на два события:

```
dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView_EditingControlShowing;
dataGridView.CellEndEdit += DataGridView_CellEndEdit;
```

Добавьте поле `TextBox editingTextBox`.

В первом событии подписываете текстбокс на собственное событие редактирования. Конечно, добавьте код проверки нужной колонки и т. п.

```
private void DataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) // реагируем только на нужную колонку
    {
        editingTextBox = (TextBox)dataGridView.EditingControl;
        editingTextBox.TextChanged += EditingTextBox_TextChanged;
    }
}
```

После окончания редактирования ячейки необходимо отписаться от события, иначе созданный `EditingControl` останется висеть в памяти, что приведёт к утечке памяти.

```
private void DataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    editingTextBox.TextChanged -= EditingTextBox_TextChanged;
}
```

В этом событии пишете код замены символов. Нужно подумать, как грамотно реализовать сохранения позиции курсора. Возможно, вместо `TextChanged` больше подойдёт событие `KeyDown` или `KeyPress`.

```
private void EditingTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    editingTextBox.Text = editingTextBox.Text.Replace(',', ':');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но с курсором беда конечно. Мне почему то кажется что есть способ проще.

Comment: Ничего не получается :(, если бы не было привязки ячейки к базе данных, можно было бы уже во время апдейта таблицы менять символы, на сам датагрид даже не позволяет ввести данные в формате не время(

Comment: Почему не получается реализовать с CellEndEdit, ошибка вылетает раньше(

Comment: ни у кого нет вариантов?