# Как добавить любое событие событие к любому control'у

Tags: c#, winforms, события

Например есть dataGridView, у него есть событие `keyDown` как добавить такое же событие, например к отдельным ячейкам, ну то есть `cellKeyDown`?

Comment: К сожалению, универсального механизма нет. Если у вас нет исходного кода класса в который нужно добавить событие, то это у вас не получится. В каждом конкретном случае нужно смотреть как этого достичь альтернативными способами. Например, в вашем случае, вы можете отслеживать событие KeyDown, проверять есть ли у вас выделенная ячейка (или ячейка в режиме редактирования) и делать то что вам нужно. Если разные получатели должны узнавать об этом событии, то можно объявить событие у формы и в KeyDown его активировать.

Comment: Опишите, чего хотите добиться. Наверняка хотите запретить/разрешить ввод некоторых символов. Лучше откажитесь от этой идеи: такая "помощь" всегда только мешает пользователю. Например, юзер не сможет вставить текст из буфера обмена, и т. д. Лучше проверяйте введенные данные с помощью события [CellValidating](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-validate-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control).

Comment: Но если очень хочется, то [можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647564/184217) (вместо `TextChanged` подписывайтесь на `KeyDown`).